# How can i find out what is causing all text on this web-page to be in italics?

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc

This default MVC-5 site is formatting everything in Italics.

I suspect the culprit is somewhere in CSS, but I searched for "italic" and am not finding it.  I put a dummy XXX in my HTML outside of any class calls, but that too is italicized.

The Page source is here: http://bpaste.net/show/FHnfOriAZFpsjiZBI5hZ/

The Site.css code is here: http://bpaste.net/show/Q9zpHbuB3xilIPuoEWff/

Comment: Better to show the whole webpage in action !

Comment: Well, this HTML and CSS doesn't cause the text to be italic, so it must be something in the files you haven't shown.